# Is there a way to get data when using Remote Debugger of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, dll-injection

I am using Visual studio with the Remote Debugger to debug some issues of the software in our customer's computer. The customer uses the software to open some files. When I am debugging, I can see some data in the IDE of VS, but the data is not enough to help me analyse the issue. Is there one way I can get the total file opened in customer's computer? (Note that the customer is not willing to send me the file)

Below is my thought:
Because in the IDE, I can see some pointer address and it points to some specific address. I can start another VS IDE and I want to write some codes to access the VS IDE doing the Remote Debugger. If I can do this, I want to access the specific address of the software in the remote conputer to get the files in costomer's computer. Is there a way to do above things? I hope I can make it clear.

Is there some technique I can use, such as injection or hack?

Comment: What language is your application using? (C/C++ or .NET)?

Comment: I am using C/C++. What is your suggestion?

Comment: The way the debugger visualizes data is quite different between native and managed apps, therefore my question. Of course, the debugger will allow you to access all data in the application, but since (I assume) you are debugging a release compile, this can be very tricky. There are ways of injecting code into an application, but I have never tried this with a remote debugger.

Comment: Since technically, you can do everything when you can debug the remote code (eventually with a lot of effort, though) and your customer is probably interested in a solution to his problem, I would again ask for the data. It can't be in the interest of the customer that finding the issue takes more time for both of you, while it doesn't increase the security for him. It's also him paying your hours, I suppose.

Comment: I am sorry that the customer is not willing to send me the data. So based on this point, I want to do something like "hacking". Could me tell me more things that I can do? As I know, developer can develop Visual Studio extension. Could I develop one extension to do below things: in this extension, I load one function (I call it FuncA) of one dll of the software I am debugging. And I pass one address (this address is the one I can see from the IDE when I am doing remote debugging) to the FuncA to do something (such as copying related data)? Is it possible?

Comment: With the debugger, you can manipulate the process as you wish (in the barest case, by manipulating the assembly the process is executing). But this requires a lot of understanding of assembly and the used system libraries. It _is_ possible, but requires a significant skill level and a lot of time.